# npm ERR! addLocal could not install in windows

Tags: node.js, windows, npm

Just started a new job and have to run node on windows (where all my coworkers are using OSX, which runs fine checking it out fresh)

When npm, I kept getting addLocal could not install, where it seems like it is trying to access temp directory in %APPDATA% (which does not any special permission) Where my coworker using same version of node and npm (but in mac) would not see any of these.

I have also tried downgrade node to 10.35, but I am getting another problem. Does anyone has any idea what might be the case?

Here is the stdout:

```
C:\Users\litehsu\workspace\myworkspace>npm install
npm WARN package.json Dependency 'grunt-sonar-runner' exists in both dependencies and devDependencies, using 'grunt-sonar-runner@2.4.3' from dependencies
npm ERR! addLocal Could not install C:\Users\litehsu\AppData\Local\Temp\npm-5440-6f1004b8\git-cache-ecdc41ed33a0\2fd99696c3f2705dcd6813454b50ad5591651427
npm ERR! addLocal Could not install C:\Users\502438~1\AppData\Local\Temp\npm-5440-6f1004b8\git-cache-87d2760d189d\e52092778d61d32bb10e3aa062bbbfaf583d2107
npm ERR! Windows_NT 6.1.7601
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install"
npm ERR! node v0.12.4
npm ERR! npm  v2.10.1
npm ERR! path C:\Users\502438914\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\karma-support\1.0.2\package.tgz
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! errno -4058

npm ERR! enoent ENOENT, scandir 'C:\Users\litehsu\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\karma-support\1.0.2\package.tgz'
npm ERR! enoent This is most likely not a problem with npm itself
npm ERR! enoent and is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\litehsu\workspace\npm-debug.log
```

thank you!

Comment: Have you tried npm cache clear?

Comment: please also check if this is same issue: [link]:( https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/6721)  good luck.

Comment: thanks @hohoho !

I have tried cache clean and I followed the link and update npm, but it is still showing the same error :(

Comment: I observed that from the error stack:C:\Users\litehsu and :C:\Users\502438~1\ , are there multiple users on the windows machine? From where you invoke looks like you are using litehsu . May be you need to manually clean up the other users?

Comment: It seems that you have grunt-sonar-runner as both dependencies and devDependencies,  I experimented with a package.json that does that.  The a npm install works fine with node 0.12.4   :  C:\Users\IBM_ADMIN>npm install
npm WARN package.json test@1.0.0 No description
npm WARN package.json test@1.0.0 No repository field.
npm WARN package.json test@1.0.0 No README data
npm WARN package.json Dependency 'grunt-sonar-runner' exists in both dependencie
s and devDependencies, using 'grunt-sonar-runner@^2.4.3' from dependencies.  It works fine with my admin account.

Comment: The error you got is not finding the file :scandir 'C:\Users\litehsu\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\karma-support\1.0.2\package.tgz'   and the file seems to be under path C:\Users\502438914\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\karma-support\1.0.2\package.tgz instead,   Something to do with your environment.

Comment: thanks @hohoho for the detail dig! I have got a mac and was able to build without problem;

the user account difference you spotted is my attempt to remove account information, they are the same on my box.

Comment: Nice you get it going,:-)  but it is a mystery why it failed on your windows though. interesting to learn why. Wonder if there are any  info in the hidden file in ./npmrc . Anyhow, thanks for posting so that we can learn more.

Answer (score 0):

Use the config to change the locations:

- Run `npm config ls -l`
- Check the path to the cache and the temp
- Change them both to a new path. For example:

  ```
  npm config set cache %USERPROFILE%\npm-cache
  npm config set tmp %USERPROFILE%\tmp
  ```

will put them in your profile folder.

Make the same edit in all `.npmrc` file locations:

- `%appdata%\npm\node_modules\npm\.npmrc`
- `%ProgramFiles%\nodejs\node_modules\npm\.npmrc`
- `%USERPROFILE%\.npmrc`

**References**

- [Troubleshooting NPM](https://github.com/npm/npm/wiki/Troubleshooting)